# Error while finding differences in frames from camera

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat current_frame;
    Mat previous_frame;
    Mat result; 
    Mat frame;

    //cap.open(-1);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        //cerr << "can not open camera or video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        cap >> current_frame;
        if (current_frame.empty())
            break;

        if (! previous_frame.empty())  {
            // subtract frames
            subtract(current_frame, previous_frame, result);
        }


        imshow("Window", result);
        waitKey(10);

        frame.copyTo(previous_frame); 
    }
}
```

When i run this program to subtract current frame from the previous frame and then show the resultant frame , it show me this error while start executing

> Unhandled exception at 0x755d812f in WK01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001fe848..

And i want to apply the same thing on recorded video

Comment: What do you ever do with frame? This might not be your bug but it looks like frame will always be empty so you'll copy an empty frame into previous frame every iteration.

Comment: @JoeRunde I want to run it on a video like on any recorded movie of 5 min , so how it can be empty ? as from 1st frame to second frame there must b a change ?

Comment: Like berak states in his answer, there is a Mat named "frame" that you never put anything in. What you've done is put the next frame into "current frame", then store "result" = "current frame" - "previous frame" then store "previous frame" = "frame". See the problem? You never put anything into "frame"

Comment: @JoeRunde Yeah i understand , you want to say that i should not assign Frame because it is emtpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the 1st frame, result is empty !

```
imshow("Window", result); // this will crash
```

also, you're copying the empty `frame` Mat to  `previous_frame`, that should be `current_frame` instead, no ?

try like:

```
   if (! previous_frame.empty())  {
       // subtract frames
       subtract(current_frame, previous_frame, result);
       imshow("Window", result); 
   }
   waitKey(10);
   current_frame.copyTo(previous_frame); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `previos_frame`. You assign value to `previous_frame` only at the and of the loop. 
I think it might be empty at the start of the while loop, so the

```
if (! previous_frame.empty())  {
        // subtract frames
        subtract(current_frame, previous_frame, result);
    }
```

block will not executed.

`previous_frame` also must be the same size as `current_frame` when subtracting.

This code(the subtract method) should determine the size of `result`, what You'd  like to show at the following line.